# Why strlen() returning 2 or 1 everytime?

Tags: c

Why doesn't strlen() return an exact value?
For example, when I input 123 it returns 2. For 12345 it returns 1. Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    long int ui,remainder,i=0,len;
    char binary[20];
    scanf("%ld",&ui);
    while(ui!=0) {
        remainder=ui%2;
        binary[i]=(char)remainder;
        printf("%d ",remainder);
        ui=ui/2;
        i++;
    }
    binary[i]='\0';
    printf("len is %ld\n",strlen(binary));
    for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--) printf("%d",binary[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen` returns the length of an array of characters until it finds the character `'\0'` (with numeric value `0`) in it. Your `binary` array is an array of characters, but you are treating them as integers as you're storing the numeric values `0` and `1`. When calculating its length, `strlen` stops when it finds the first `0` you wrote.

To get the answer you need, change the `binary` definition to `char binary[20] = { 0 };`, save the `remainder` values as ASCII characters (`binary[i] = '0' + (char)remainder;`), and print them as characters `printf("%c ",binary[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

The reason it isn't working is because of how you're using `binary`.

The `strlen` function is meant to operate on NULL terminated strings.  But `binary` isn't treaded as a string, but as an array of bytes.

The `strlen` function searches until it find a null bytes, i.e. a byte with a value of 0.  In the case of "123", the value 0 appears after two bytes.  In the case of "12345", the value 0 appears after one byte.  This explains the output you're getting.

Also, you're using `len` without initializing it.  This leads to undefined behavior.  You want to set it to `i` after you exit the `while` loop.  You also need to change the format specifier for your first `printf` from `%d` to `%ld` since `remainder` is declared as a `long int`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here binary is a char so it's '0' + value print it out that way as well;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    long int ui,remainder,i=0,len;
    char binary[20] = {0};
    scanf("%ld",&ui);
    if (ui==0) { binary[i] = '0'; i++; } // Special case for zero
    while(ui!=0) {
        remainder=ui%2;
        binary[i]=(char)remainder + '0';
        printf("%d ",remainder);
        ui=ui/2;
        i++;
    }
    binary[i]='\0';
    printf("len is %ld %s\n",len = strlen(binary), binary);
    for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--) 
        printf("%c",binary[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

For my run below I got

32

0 0 0 0 0 1 len is 6 000001

100000

Comment: If input is `"0"`, the output is `"len is 0 \n"`.